# Can't get currentUser in Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Try to see user page `/dashboard` after Firebase authentication, but every time the error occurs. From root and use `<Link to={"/dashboard"}` is working. But directly url is not working. Header calls `firebase.currentUser()` but it can't.

The error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null

The code:

*auth.js*

```
class Auth extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (!user) {
        this.props.history.push("/");
      } else {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.authenticating ? (
          <div className="loader">
            <Loader loading={this.state.loading} />
          </div>
        ) : (
          this.props.children
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

*header.js*

```
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    return (
      <p>{user.uid}</p>
    )
  }
}
```

*dashbpoard.js*

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Auth>
          <p>Dashboard</p>
        </Auth>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users):

> Note: currentUser might also be null because the auth object has not finished initializing. If you use an observer to keep track of the user's sign-in status, you don't need to handle this case.

This is why it is erroring out for you in case of direct URLs but not otherwise. You can choose to get around this by conditionally render the `userId` in header:

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
return user && (
  <p>{user.uid}</p>
)
```

This is assuming that change in Authentication would trigger a re-render of the component from one of the higher components. As note says you can use `onAuthStateChanged` callback to make sure that component re-renders.

```
const userContext = useContext(UserContext);

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  // Assuming that it has a setUser function
  userContext.setUser(user);
});
```

and use the value from context in Header.

[Docs for Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment. I have successfully fixed a bug!

Comment: @k10a you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped